# How to run PySpark with installed packages?

Tags: pyspark, graphframes

Normally, when I run `pyspark` with `graphframes` I have to use this command:

```sh
pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12
```

In the first time run this, this will install the packages `graphframes` but not the next time. In the `.bashrc` file, I have already added:

```
export SPARK_OPTS="--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12"
```

But I cannot import the packages if I am not adding the option `--packages`.

How can I run `pyspark` with `graphframes` with this simple command?

```
pyspark
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a wrapper script like `myspark.sh` that triggers `pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12`, that would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Yes that is the simplest way but I don't want to add the `--packages` after `pyspark` or `spark-submit` every time I submit a job.